# Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused in Gitlab-ci

Tags: networking, ubuntu, localhost, gitlab

I'm using Gitlab enterprise trial edition and setup gitlab-runner on same server. Setup pipelines to build projects using gitlab-runner but getting below error when build my code :

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.0 (413da38)
on mypc10.local (db1052ee)
Using Docker executor with image php:7.1.1 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Using docker image     sha256:66096b6df47a96fc0e86eb84a6c1c2d5c34ce55e2ddc70cb1cad17910b58ee17    for predefined container...
Pulling docker image php:7.1.1 ...
Using docker image php:7.1.1    ID=sha256:608e59384e11266142f9eb5e66b4b887596371e910e6b20e797717961947e3c4    for build container...
Running on runner-db1052ee-project-2-concurrent-0 via nls10...
Fetching changes...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-    token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@mypc10.local/root/myproject.git/': Failed to     connect to 172.18.0.1 port 80: Operation timed out
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I able to resolve `mypc10.local` hostname using hosts file, even i tried to setup localhost, 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.24 on gitlab but getting same error.
Also able to telnet on `80` port using my hosts name.

anyone have idea why getting this error ?

Answer (score 1):

For a while already you need to use **https** for this to work, so setup your gitlab environment with **ssl certificate**.

You can also check this post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003101/gitlab-runner-unable-to-clone-repository-via-http/35759913#35759913

Comment: The question (somewhat unclearly) says that the OP was able to telnet on port 80.   How do you reconcile that with your implication that **http** doesn’t work?   (That is what you’re saying, right?)

Comment: @Scott This is specific for gitlab-runner which needs https. So although port 80 is working (this config is unable to authenticate), and then the whole CI pipeline fails... I believe there could be better error messaging, but that's how I solved similar problem...